# How can I disable scrolling on the Google Maps mobile layout?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, mobile

I am developing mobile sites with Google Maps embedded via the Google Maps API. I have been able to stop certain types of behavior but have been unable to find a good way to stop the map from scrolling as I finger scroll down the page on the iPhone. Here is the code I am using:

```
<script>
function initialize() {
  var mapElem = document.getElementById("map"),
      myOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.8965,-84.063),
        navigationControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions: {
          style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL,
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
        },
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
        scrollwheel: false,
        backgroundColor: '#f2efe9',
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      },
      map = new google.maps.Map(mapElem, myOptions);
}
</script>
<script src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize'></script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Blog post on the subject: [Disable Google Maps scrolling on mobile layout](https://coderwall.com/p/pgm8xa)

Answer (score 54):

Validate whether `ontouchend` is available in `document`.

```
var myOptions = {
    // your other options...
    draggable: !("ontouchend" in document)
};
map = new google.maps.Map(mapElem, myOptions);
```

Comment: The best answer! Thanks!

Comment: This does not work for me anymore. I have seen on several different computers running windows 10 and chrome have that.

Answer (score 39):

```
draggable: false
```

[As stated in the API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapOptions)

Comment: that drops live dragging functionality but doesn't stop the map from removing the default touch-move. I need the map embed to stop accepting the touch-move event.

Comment: My first suggestion would be to just disable touch events on the view. However assuming you're working with multiplatform, may I suggest a static map instead? http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Comment: Draggable as of 2017 is deprecated. "Deprecated: Deprecated in 2017. To disable dragging on the map, you can use the gestureHandling property, and set it to "none"."

See: [Draggable](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions.draggable)

Answer (score 9):

In your css:

```
    pointer-events: none;
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer - use media queries instead of js to sort it out

Comment: While it works, i usually avoid this method because it is not yet in the HTML5 standard, even though most browsers extend this functionality from SVG to HTML anyway. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Unfortunately this solution disables all touch controls with the map, not just scrolling as per the OP's question. The zoom buttons are rendered useless, as well as all the other links displayed on Google Maps such as Google reviews, contact details, switching map mode views and 'View larger map', so not a great solution for most people.

Answer (score 7):

You can also try 
a) a server side mobile detection liked mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524301/detect-mobile-browser) and then b) include it in your .php (e.g. header.php or footer.php) file, like so:

```
function isMobile() {
    return preg_match("/(android|avantgo|blackberry|bolt|boost|cricket|docomo|fone|hiptop|mini|mobi|palm|phone|pie|tablet|up\.browser|up\.link|webos|wos)/i", $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
}
```

Embed it in your code:

```
var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 18,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.345, 12.345),
        scrollwheel: false,
        <?php echo(isMobile()) ? 'draggable: false' : ''; ?>
    };
```

Note that this of course only works if you have Google Maps Javascript code embedded in your php file.

Comment: It looks like you've put a bracket in the wrong place. Did you mean `<?php echo(isMobile() ? 'draggable: false' : ''); ?>`?

Comment: Hi Beetle, the brackets in my example should be correct (it is recommended to avoid "stacking" ternary expressions. PHP's behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single statement is non-obvious. Please also see http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your myOptions list:

```
gestureHandling: 'cooperative'
```

This is from the Google Maps JS API documentation. I implemented a similar functionality on my mobile maps web app.

Answer (score 1):

i am a newb, so i give an noob answer:

try putting the width at 90%, so you allow space for the finger to go down and up witout touching the map.

For me it worked :)

Comment: I think it's always valid to look at an alternative solution as well

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the answer in another StackOverflow question. That solution worked for me with my map on my Android using Chrome at least.

[Embed Google Maps on page without overriding iPhone scroll behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534888/embed-google-maps-on-page-without-overriding-iphone-scroll-behavior)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it with media query responsive techniques.

HTML at the footer of the page (just above `</body>`):

```
<div class="jrespond"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.jrespond{
  width: 30px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px){
  .jrespond{
    width: 20px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
  .jrespond{
    width: 10px;
  }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
if(jrespond == 10){
  // Do mobile function
}

if(jrespond == 20){    
  // Do tablet function
}

if(jrespond >= 30){
  // Do desktop function
}

**/// Google** map snippet
var isDraggable = true;
if(jrespond == 10){
  var isDraggable = false;
}

var myOptions = {    
  zoom: 12,
  center: myLatlng1,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  draggable: isDraggable
}
```