# Detect mobile browser

Tags: php, mobile, detect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simplest way to detect a mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117555/simplest-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device)

I have a site and I want to detect which browser is used and redirect them.
I have a php index and the code must be in php.
I've found many sites but they don't work or they don't detect many mobile browsers.
Do you know of any good code or tutorials that can detect many mobile browsers?

Comment: not sure if this is too much for what you need, but you may want to have a look: http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/nphp/

Comment: see: http://mobiledetect.net/ seems the simplest way...

Comment: Dough in contrast this one is easier to include and actually works !! i'd sugest you vote for @iamandrus as answer

Comment: You could use a third party api service like https://useragentinfo.co or see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44982837/395676. It could detect browser version, OS version and device type.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Have my user agent code:

```
<?php

/* USER-AGENTS
================================================== */
function check_user_agent ( $type = NULL ) {
        $user_agent = strtolower ( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );
        if ( $type == 'bot' ) {
                // matches popular bots
                if ( preg_match ( "/googlebot|adsbot|yahooseeker|yahoobot|msnbot|watchmouse|pingdom\.com|feedfetcher-google/", $user_agent ) ) {
                        return true;
                        // watchmouse|pingdom\.com are "uptime services"
                }
        } else if ( $type == 'browser' ) {
                // matches core browser types
                if ( preg_match ( "/mozilla\/|opera\//", $user_agent ) ) {
                        return true;
                }
        } else if ( $type == 'mobile' ) {
                // matches popular mobile devices that have small screens and/or touch inputs
                // mobile devices have regional trends; some of these will have varying popularity in Europe, Asia, and America
                // detailed demographics are unknown, and South America, the Pacific Islands, and Africa trends might not be represented, here
                if ( preg_match ( "/phone|iphone|itouch|ipod|symbian|android|htc_|htc-|palmos|blackberry|opera mini|iemobile|windows ce|nokia|fennec|hiptop|kindle|mot |mot-|webos\/|samsung|sonyericsson|^sie-|nintendo/", $user_agent ) ) {
                        // these are the most common
                        return true;
                } else if ( preg_match ( "/mobile|pda;|avantgo|eudoraweb|minimo|netfront|brew|teleca|lg;|lge |wap;| wap /", $user_agent ) ) {
                        // these are less common, and might not be worth checking
                        return true;
                }
        }
        return false;
}

?>
```

How to use:

```
<?php
$ismobile = check_user_agent('mobile');
if($ismobile) {
return 'yes';
} else {
return 'no';
}
?>
```

Comment: nice implementation. Kudos!

Comment: This code still works. But some things have changed. Apple iPhone puts Mozilla in front of their user agent now. So first check mobile and then desktop.

Comment: in the line for mobile, add a |Mobile| to detect firefox mobile on android. Besides great script finally i found a true php one that worked thumbs up, kuddos !

Comment: Oh and if some device isnt working just ad an echo $user_agent;
to find its name. somehow i noticed the script halts when it couldnt detect (firefox)

Comment: using to standard android browser and its not working!

Comment: How do we keep MS Edge from being detected as mobile?

Comment: Says its desktop on iphone 6 even after i put mobile first

Answer (score 4):

At work, we use [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) - there are millions of different browsers out there, and you're better of to re-use the work that others with experience did in that regard than implementing your own solution.

Comment: Might be helpful to show or link to an example of using WURFL in PHP to accomplish what the @Gromdroid wants.