# Different Wordpress menus at different screen sizes

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am trying display different wordpress menus depending on the device/screen width.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 959) {
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'primary', 'container' => '', 'menu_id' => 'menu' ) ); ?>
    } else {
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'mobile' ) ); ?>
    }
});
</script>
```

I've tried using this code, as well as several other variations, but nothing seems to be working. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance
Willem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this:

```
<?php

/* USER-AGENTS
================================================== */
function check_user_agent ( $type = NULL ) {
        $user_agent = strtolower ( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );
        if ( $type == 'bot' ) {
                // matches popular bots
                if ( preg_match ( "/googlebot|adsbot|yahooseeker|yahoobot|msnbot|watchmouse|pingdom\.com|feedfetcher-google/", $user_agent ) ) {
                        return true;
                        // watchmouse|pingdom\.com are "uptime services"
                }
        } else if ( $type == 'browser' ) {
                // matches core browser types
                if ( preg_match ( "/mozilla\/|opera\//", $user_agent ) ) {
                        return true;
                }
        } else if ( $type == 'mobile' ) {
                // matches popular mobile devices that have small screens and/or touch inputs
                // mobile devices have regional trends; some of these will have varying popularity in Europe, Asia, and America
                // detailed demographics are unknown, and South America, the Pacific Islands, and Africa trends might not be represented, here
                if ( preg_match ( "/phone|iphone|itouch|ipod|symbian|android|htc_|htc-|palmos|blackberry|opera mini|iemobile|windows ce|nokia|fennec|hiptop|kindle|mot |mot-|webos\/|samsung|sonyericsson|^sie-|nintendo/", $user_agent ) ) {
                        // these are the most common
                        return true;
                } else if ( preg_match ( "/mobile|pda;|avantgo|eudoraweb|minimo|netfront|brew|teleca|lg;|lge |wap;| wap /", $user_agent ) ) {
                        // these are less common, and might not be worth checking
                        return true;
                }
        }
        return false;
}

?>
```

and then:

```
<?php
$ismobile = check_user_agent('mobile');
if($ismobile) {
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'mobile' ) );
} else {
wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'primary', 'container' => '', 'menu_id' => 'menu' ) );
}
?>
```

This doesn't work on the device size but rather whether or not the site is being accessed from a mobile device.

Source: [Detect mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524301/detect-mobile-browser)

Thanks
Willem

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, wp_nav_menu just output the menu html, so on the client side, you would get this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 959) {
    <div>....menu html....</div>
    } else {
    <div>....menu html....</div>
    }
});
</script>
```

I think there should be javascript errors there.

Try this:

```
<div id="menu_a" style="display:none">
  <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'primary', 'container' => '', 'menu_id' => 'menu' ) ); ?>
</div>
<div id="menu_b" style="display:none">
   <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'mobile' ) ); ?>
</div>
<script>
$(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 959) {
    $("#menu_a").show();
    } else {
    $("#menu_b").show();
    }
});
</script>
```

Or in response design style, no Javascript involved:

```
   @media all and (max-width: 958px) { #menu_a{display:none};}
   @media all and (min-width: 959px) { #menu_b{display:none};}
```

Comment: Hi Andrew

Thanks for the reply, I want to stay away from display: none for SEO reasons. So I'm really looking for a way to only call in the relevant php for whichever menu is applicable.

Thanks

Comment: You can move the display:none to css, but I'm not sure it's affect SEO or not. Actually you should try response design, which do not use Javascript at all, like this: @media all and (min-width:  959px) {}

Comment: My concern for the SEO is twofold: since the menu structures will be very similar I'm concerned about duplicate content, especially since it will appear on every page. My second concern is that Google frowns upon elements that are hidden. Thanks

Comment: The website is currently being made responsive, which is why I need this second menu. But as I said, I don't want to make use of hidden html elements. Thanks

Comment: I've done some more reading, it seems this can be done with ajax? But I have no experience with that... Otherwise what about using a php if statement that detects whether the site is being accessed by a mobile device(both phones and tablets) or by a computer?
Thanks