# Full screen google map scrolling on touch devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, mobile

I have a contacts page with google map. When user scrolls down map covers full screen on mobile device.

I want to allow users to scroll the map only on click+drag and not on simple scrolling, so that user could scroll out of the map.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531052/how-can-i-disable-scrolling-on-the-google-maps-mobile-layout

Answer (score 2):

Two methods i know using Hammer Js to handle the Double Taps.

**One** is to add an overlay on the map and change its `z-index` value as required. The bonus with the overlay is that no additional code is needed to disable any interaction on the map if needed, e.g markers click and controls.

**Two** is to use the in-build Gmaps `.setOptions({draggable: true/false}` function.

**Method one Demo** Note. Adjust CSS width, height, position for your Map(s)

http://jsfiddle.net/gmqctmkd/

**CSS**

```
.overlay {
position:absolute;
height:300px;
width:100%;
background:transparent;
z-index:99;
top:0;
left:0;
}
```

**Code**

```
mc.on("doubbletap", function(ev) {

 $(".overlay").css("z-index", "1");

})
```

**Method Two Demo** Using `.setOptions({draggable: true/false}`

http://jsfiddle.net/oom5uevt/

**Code**

```
// set map Options to disable drag.

map.setOptions({draggable: false});

// enable drag 

mc.on("doubbletap", function(ev) {

map.setOptions({draggable: true});

})
```

Comment: I am actually looking for a solution to allow user to pan on the map only on double tap + drag.

Comment: Double tap on map, on second tap leave finger on screen and move it to move the map.

Comment: @sniurs So instead of click a button, double tap on the map. ok then i suggest using Hammers Js plugging to handle the double taps -- demo --  http://jsfiddle.net/gmqctmkd/