# How to scroll a google map by clicking on a button in Android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to move a google map into an activity Android without using the fingers but only using four buttons (objects) with the directions: left, right, top and bottom.

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation, you can use **draggable:false** in preventing maps from being dragged. 
You can use this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#MapOptions) for more information.

Also, here is a related article that you can refer to:
[How can I disable scrolling on the Google Maps mobile layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531052/how-can-i-disable-scrolling-on-the-google-maps-mobile-layout)

Regarding the controls, I think you can actually add custom controls aside from the existing and default controls. Note that few rules are necessary to be followed:

- Define appropriate CSS for the control element(s) to display.
- Handle interaction with the user or the map through event handlers for either map property changes or user events (for example, 'click' events).
- Create a `<div>` element to hold the control and add this element to the Map's controls property.

Please see this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls) for more information and examples.

Hope this one will help.